# How does `yes` write to file so quickly?

Tags: bash, coreutils, write, yes

Let me give an example:

```
$ timeout 1 yes "GNU" > file1
$ wc -l file1
11504640 file1
```

```
$ for ((sec0=`date +%S`;sec<=$(($sec0+5));sec=`date +%S`)); do echo "GNU" >> file2; done
$ wc -l file2
1953 file2
```

Here you can see that the command `yes` writes `11504640` lines in a second while I can write only `1953` lines in 5 seconds using bash's `for` and `echo`.

As suggested in the comments, there are various tricks to make it more efficient but none come close to matching the speed of `yes`:

```
$ ( while :; do echo "GNU" >> file3; done) & pid=$! ; sleep 1 ; kill $pid
[1] 3054
$ wc -l file3
19596 file3
```

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'while true; do echo "GNU" >> file4; done'
$ wc -l file4
18912 file4
```

These can write up to 20 thousand lines in a second. And they can be further improved to:

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'while true; do echo "GNU"; done >> file5' 
$ wc -l file5
34517 file5
```

```
$ ( while :; do echo "GNU"; done >> file6 ) & pid=$! ; sleep 1 ; kill $pid
[1] 5690
$ wc -l file6
40961 file6
```

These get us up to 40 thousand lines in a second. Better, but still a far cry from `yes` which can write about 11 million lines in a second!

So, **how does `yes` write to file so quickly?**

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: In the second example, you have two external command invocations for every iteration of the loop, and `date` is somewhat heavy-weight, plus the shell has to re-open the output stream for `echo` for every loop iteration. In the first example, there is only a single command invocation with a single output redirection, and the command is extremely lightweight. The two are in no way comparable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you're right `date` may be heavy-weight, see edit to my question.

Comment: `timeout 1 $(while true; do echo "GNU">>file2; done;)` is the wrong way to use `timeout`  since the `timeout` command will only start once the command substitution is finished. Use `timeout 1 sh -c 'while true; do echo "GNU">>file2; done'`.

Comment: A shell interprets its programs, and invokes them with a lot of argument preprocessing.  This takes time, and that is what you see.

Comment: summary of answers: by only spending CPU time on `write(2)` system calls, not on boatloads of other syscalls, shell overhead, or even process creation in your very first example (which runs and waits for `date` for every line printed to the file).  One second of writing is barely enough for it to bottleneck on disk I/O (rather than CPU/memory), on a modern system with lots of RAM.  If allowed to run longer, the difference would be smaller. (Depending on how bad a bash implementation you use, and relative speed of CPU and disk, you might not even saturate disk I/O with bash).

Comment: You get another small improvement with `printf`. Try this: `( while :; do printf "%s\n" "GNU"; done >> file7 ) & pid=$! ; sleep 1 ; kill $pid`

Comment: @WalterA: Whether you get an improvement (i.e. more lines persisted in file per unit time) for `printf "%s\n"` vs `echo` (both are shell builtins) may depend on your implementation. I get a worsening on vanilla bash v5.08.18 with a total 16GB RAM and a CPU buzzing along to take care only of OS chores... It actually surprised me, but I repeated the experiment over 30 times and worked out averages as 342,742 lines for `echo` and "only" 292,728 lines for `printf "%s\n"`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### In a nutshell:

`yes` exhibits similar behavior to most other standard utilities which typically [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_443) to a [FILE STREAM](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_74.htm) with output buffered by the libC via [`stdio`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html). These only do the syscall [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) every some 4kb *(16kb or 64kb)* or whatever the output block [`BUFSIZ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setbuf.html) is . `echo` is a `write()` per *`GNU`*. That's a *lot* of [mode-switching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1860253/2955202) *(which is not, apparently, as costly as a [context-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch#User_and_kernel_mode_switching))*.

And that's not at all to mention that, besides its initial optimization loop, `yes` is a very simple, tiny, compiled C loop and your shell loop is in no way comparable to a compiler optimized program.

---

#### But I was wrong:

When I said before that `yes` used `stdio`, I only assumed it did because it behaves a lot like those that do. This was not correct - it only emulates their behavior in this way. What it actually does is very like an analog to the thing I did below with the shell: it first loops to conflate its arguments *(or `y` if none)* until they might grow no more without exceeding `BUFSIZ`.

A comment from the [source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/yes.c) immediately preceding the relevant `for` loop states:

```C
/* Buffer data locally once, rather than having the
large overhead of stdio buffering each item.  */
```

`yes` does its own `write()`s thereafter.

---

#### Digression:

*(As originally included in the question and retained for context to a possibly informative explanation already written here)*:

> I've tried `timeout 1 $(while true; do echo "GNU">>file2; done;)` but unable to stop loop.

The `timeout` problem you have with the command substitution - I think I get it now and can explain why it doesn't stop. `timeout` doesn't start because its command-line is never run. Your shell forks a child shell, opens a pipe on its stdout and reads it. It will stop reading when the child quits, and then it will interpret all the child wrote for `$IFS` mangling and glob expansions, and with the results, it will replace everything from `$(` to the matching `)`.

But if the child is an endless loop that never writes to the pipe, then the child never stops looping, and `timeout`'s command-line is never completed before *(as I guess)* you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and kill the child loop. So `timeout` can  *never* kill the loop which needs to complete before it can start.

---

#### Other `timeout`s:

... simply aren't as relevant to your performance issues as the amount of time your shell program must spend switching between user- and kernel-mode to handle output. `timeout`, though, is not as flexible as a shell might be for this purpose: where shells excel is in their ability to mangle arguments and manage other processes.

As is noted elsewhere, simply moving your *`[fd-num] >> named_file`* redirection to the loop's output target rather than only directing output there for the command looped over can substantially improve performance because that way at least the [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) syscall need only be done the once. This also is done below with the `|` pipe targeted as output for the inner loops.

---

#### Direct comparison:

You might do like:

```bsh
for cmd in  exec\ yes 'while echo y; do :; done'
do      set +m
        sh  -c '{ sleep 1; kill "$$"; }&'"$cmd" | wc -l
        set -m
done
```

```
256659456
505401
```

Which is *kind* of like the command sub relationship described before, but there's no pipe and the child is backgrounded until it kills the parent. In the `yes` case the parent has actually been replaced since the child was spawned, but the shell calls `yes` by overlaying its own process with the new one and so the PID remains the same and its zombie child still knows who to kill after all.

---

#### Bigger buffer:

Now let's see about increasing the shell's `write()` buffer.

```bsh
IFS="
";    set y ""              ### sets up the macro expansion       
until [ "${512+1}" ]        ### gather at least 512 args
do    set "$@$@";done       ### exponentially expands "$@"
printf %s "$*"| wc -c       ### 1 write of 512 concatenated "y\n"'s
```

```
1024
```

I chose that number because output strings any longer than 1kb were getting split out into separate `write()`'s for me. And so here's the loop again:

```bsh
for cmd in 'exec  yes' \
           'until [ "${512+:}" ]; do set "$@$@"; done
            while printf %s "$*"; do :; done'
do      set +m
        sh  -c $'IFS="\n"; { sleep 1; kill "$$"; }&'"$cmd" shyes y ""| wc -l
        set -m
done
```

```
268627968
15850496
```

That's 300 times the amount of data written by the shell in the same amount of time for this test than the last. Not too shabby. But it's not `yes`.

---

#### Felated:

As requested, there is a more thorough description than the mere code comments on what is done here at [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250626/52934).

Comment: @heemayl - maybe? im not totally sure i understand what youre asking? when a program uses stdio to write output it does with either no buffering *(like stderr by default)* or line buffering *(to terminals by default)* or block buffering *(basically most other stuff is set this way by default)*. im a little unclear on what sets the size of the output buffer - but it's usually some of 4kb. and so the stdio lib functions will gather their output until they can write a whole block. `dd` is one standard tool which definitely does not use stdio, for example. most others do.

Comment: The shell version is doing `open` (existing) `write` AND `close` (which I believe still waits for flush), AND creating a new process and executing `date`, for each loop.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - go to [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27060623#27060623). and what you say is not necessarily true, as you can see there. For example, doing that `wc -l` loop with `bash` for me gets 1/5th of the output the `sh` loop does - `bash` manages a little over 100k `writes()` to `dash`'s 500k.

Comment: Sorry I was ambiguous; I meant the shell version in the question, which at the time I read it had only the original version with the `for((sec0=\`date +%S\`;...` to control time and the redirection in the loop, not the subsequent improvements.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - its fine. the answer was wrong anyway about some fundamental points, and should be pretty much correct  now, as l hope.

Answer (score 21):

A better question would be why is your shell writing the file so slowly. Any self-contained compiled program that uses file writing syscalls responsibly (not flushing every character at a time) would do it reasonably quicky. What you are doing, is writing lines in an *interpreted* language (the shell), and in addition you do a *lot* of unnecessary input output operations. What `yes`does:

- opens a file for writing
- calls optimized and compiled functions for
  writing to a stream
- the stream is buffered, so a syscall (an expensive switch to kernel mode) happens very rarely, in large chunks
- closes a file

What your script does:

- reads in a line of code
- interprets the code, making a lot of extra operations to actually parse your input and figure out what to do
- for each iteration of while loop (which is probably not cheap in an interpreted language):

  - call the `date` external command and store its output (only in the original version - in the revised version you gain a factor of 10 by not doing this)
  - test whether the loop's termination condition is met
  - *open* a file in append mode
  - parse `echo` command, recognize it (with some pattern matching code) as a shell builtin, call parameter expansion and everything else on the argument "GNU", and finally write the line to the open file
  - *close* the file again
  - repeat the process

The expensive parts: the whole interpretation is extremely expensive (bash is doing an awful lot of preprocessing of all the input - your string could potentially contain variable substitution, process substitution, brace expansion, escape characters and more), every call of a builtin is probably a switch statement with redirect to a function that deals with the builtin, and very importantly, you open and close a file for each and every line of output. You could put `>> file` outside the while loop to make it **a lot quicker**, but you're still in an interpreted language. You are quite lucky that `echo` is a shell builtin, not an external command - otherwise, your loop would involve creating a new process (fork & exec) on every single iteration. Which would grind the process to a halt - you saw how costly that is when you had the `date` command in the loop.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers have addressed the main points. On a side note, you can increase the throughput of your while loop by writing to the output file at the end of the computation. Compare:

```
$ i=0;time while  [ $i -le 1000 ]; do ((++i)); echo "GNU" >>/tmp/f; done;

real    0m0.080s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.037s
```

with

```
$ i=0;time while  [ $i -le 1000 ]; do ((++i)); echo "GNU"; done>>/tmp/f;

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Comment: Yes, this matters and writing speed (at-least) doubles  in my case